# Defining ID for HTML element using Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have written this:

```
@Html.TextBox("PhoneAdmin", new { id = "phone" })
```

My goal was to have the id of "phone" for this textbox because a jQuery plugin I downloaded to use is using that ID as a masked text box to format phone numbers.

But it is not working, if I go to "Inspect" on it, I will see this:

```
<input id="PhoneAdmin" name="PhoneAdmin" type="text" value="{ id = phone }">
```

and it shows up like this in the browser:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @E.B : Ok I tired..no change, still the same.

Comment: sorry, no need for "@", just check the answer. I'll open project and find a sample :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what I did somewhere I needed this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(task.Name, "Details", new { id = task.Id })
```

you just must find the correct constructor.

and here is what you want:

```
@Html.TextBox("PhoneAdmin", "+355699abc",new {id="phone" })
```

Comment: Ok that's what I should have written:  @Html.TextBox("PhoneAdmin", null ,new { id = "phone" })   your comment about using the the right constructor helped.